# Swift programatic constraints bottom margin not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to set up a programatic constraint between the bottom margin of a uiview and the bottom margin of a scroll view. However, xcode gives me some errors and the text looks at best out of place, sometimes it doesnt appear at all

So basically I have a uiview with size 400 let's say and a scroll view as parent. 
I am trying to add a distance of 300 between the scroll view bottom and the uiview bottom. I need to do this programatically as there is no way to tell how many views will be present at a given time on screen, thus I need to change the constraints between them programatically.

My code is

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item:container1,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem:scrollFrame,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
            multiplier:0,
            constant:400)
        )
```

But it doesnt work...Apparently, on simulator, the uiview is positioned at 400 from the top, or something, as it moves down when I increase the constant (tried with 600)

Xcode prints the following error:

```
2015-03-25 12:38:13.342 GraficTest[6612:707546] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be906b0 V:|-(48)-[UIView:0x7be8e780]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7be90340 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bfd80e0 V:[UIView:0x7be8e780(257)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf6a940 UIView:0x7be8e780.bottom == + 600>"
)
```

Can you please help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I could infer few things:

1. There is a constraint to place UIView 48 points from top of UIScrollView
2. The UIView has height constraint of 257 points
3. The UIView bottom must be placed 600 points above UIScrollView bottom.

As UIScrollView will have some height let's say X, from above constraints it should be

X = 48 + 257 + 600 = 905

But this apparently is not the case and hence Layout system is not able to satisfy all the constraints.

By removing the height constraint from UIView you may be able to fix the issue.